# SqlDataReader.NextResult() dealing with 0 results

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to c# programming and I have inherited this script I'm trying to work on.

I'm calling a procedure with 3 results sets. The first result set will always return 1 record. The second result set may return 1 or 0 records. The third result set may return 1 or 0 records.

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("MyProc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", param1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", param2));

pageData = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (pageData.Read()){
   // Do some stuff here
}
Response.Write("HERE");
pageData.NextResult();                          
while (pageData.Read()){
   // Do some stuff here
}
Response.Write("HERE2");
pageData.NextResult();                          
while (pageData.Read()){
    Response.Write("HERE3");
}
```

In my test case, the first record set returns 1 result, the second one 0 and the third 1. In this case, it outputs the first "HERE", but skips the second and third.

I need to skip the second set if there are 0 results for it and go to the third

Comment: NextResult reruns a bool. Does your call return true? If the 2nd here is never displayed a exception is being thrown and you are silently throwing it away. Also you need to be using `using` statements to dispose of your reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SqlDataReader.HasRows` property to determine if there are any results.

```
pageData.NextResult();                          
if (pageData.HasRows)
{
 while (pageData.Read()){
   // Do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I tested that out and got the same result: "HERE" shows up, but "HERE2" and "HERE3" do not

Comment: You need to modify your program to have the `Console.WriteLine("HERE2/3")` inside of the `if (pageData.HasRows)` block

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like the following:

```
pageData = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (pageData.HasRows) {
    while (pageData.Read()){
       // Do some stuff here
    }

    pageData.NextResult();                          
}
```

Hope that helps.